# disabling cache for development Purposes in Typo3 Version 6.2.9

Tags: caching, typo3-6.2.x

I'm very new to Typo3 and am struggling with a few cached images that refuse to update.

There has to be a option to deactivate all caching somewhere, and to flush everything. I need to know how.

Comment: Describe the case pls

Comment: It's all in the description. I want to disable caching in Typo3 because it saves resized versions of images that are subject to change. When I change the original images on the server, the resized images in the caches of the old ones stay in use. Disabling cache would force the server to recompile these files every single time the page is reloaded. This slows down live pages considerably but makes sense for a Website in development stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have been expecting to find was one button that fixes it all. What I actually found was the following:

The directory */fileadmin/_processed_* contains resized images that the website creates and stores for later reuse, deleting the folder's content prompts the website to recreate everything from scratch, thus reflecting any changes to the original images that are stored elsewhere.

The directory */typo3temp/* runs a similar role like the one mentioned above, it contains semitemporary data from some installed extensions (unlike above not limited to image files). If a particular extension is causing trouble you might find (and empty) it's cache in this directory
*/typo3temp/Cache* appears to be of interest.

The Install tool accesible from the backend provides a few useful functions, most notably the *clear all cache* found under the tab *important functions*.
Furthermore  there is a tab *clean up* which allow clearing *cache_imagesizes*, *cache_md5params*, *cache_typo3temp_log* amongst some other things that don't seem to be of greater interest.

Comment: like already stated I'm pretty new to typo3, so i'll ask anyone more knowledgable than myself to check and improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I switched to TYPO3 6.0
It was caused by the FAL (file abstraction layer).
The only way, displaying a newer version of the picture was to rename it such like:

```
oldpicture = _picture
newpicture = oldpicture
```